# Azure Data Factory V2 - Calling a stored procedure with an output parameter

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to create an ADF v2 pipeline that calls a stored procedure in Azure SQL Data Warehouse.  The stored procedure has two parameters, one of which is an output parameter.  The stored procedure loads a staging table.  The number of records loaded into the staging table is then assigned to the output parameter.

Is there a way to use the value of the output parameter later in my pipeline?

In SSIS I would have used a row count transform to assign the value into a parameter and the access that parameter later on in the same package.

Comment: I am also looking for same ... if you have solution the post that, it will save lot of time

Comment: I have similar problem also. If you have any tips - please share.

Answer (score 2):

Work-Around:
As a workaround to implement this functionality, we can use Lookup Activity as an alternative. In that we can execute the stored procedures – along with flexibility to capture the output as below.
Note: This solution/workaround is helpful if the output to be captured from storedproc is a single row and not a multiple rows.`Lookup Activity with output parameter:

```
{
    "name": "Test_Lookup",
    "type": "Lookup",
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
        "retry": 0,
        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
        "secureOutput": false
    },
    "typeProperties": {
        "source": {
            "type": "SqlSource",
            "sqlReaderStoredProcedureName": "[dbo].[sp_testproc]",
            "storedProcedureParameters": {
                "TEST": {
                    "type": "Int32",
                    "value": "1"
                }
            }
        },
        "dataset": {
            "referenceName": "AzureDBDataset",
            "type": "DatasetReference"
        }
    }
}

Lookup Activity without output parameter
{
    "name": "Test_Lookup",
    "type": "Lookup",
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
        "retry": 0,
        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
        "secureOutput": false
    },
    "typeProperties": {
        "source": {
            "type": "SqlSource",
            "sqlReaderStoredProcedureName": "[dbo].[sp_testproc]"
        },
        "dataset": {
            "referenceName": "AzureDBDataset",
            "type": "DatasetReference"
        }
    }
}
```

Now let’s use the below code in the Dynamic content to access the output value from the created stored procedure

Dynamic Expression - `@activity('Test_Lookup').output.firstRow.TEST`
Stored Procedures with output Parameters in Azure Data Factory http://naveensql23.blogspot.com/2018/07/stored-procedures-with-output.html

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't do this.  The ADFv2 Stored Procedure Activity does not support output parameters.  I haven't found where we can request feature updates, but this is very needed feature.

Instead you have to use a work around such as Naveen suggested.  Naveen's suggestion of calling a Lookup Activity to call a stored procedure is great when you only have one item that you're returning.

To get around this I'm doing the following for each item I'm interested in:

1. Send the original Stored Procedure Activity the pipeline ID and json input from a previous step.
2. Log the pipeline ID and any other data you want returned.
3. Call the Lookup Activity passing the pipeline ID as the lookup key to get the data you wanted in step 2.  NOTE: You'll also have to send in another parameter.  For me it is the filename to see if I should continue processing that file.

Also of note: The Lookup Activity is not using an output parameter, but the return value of the stored procedure.  This return value can be multiple rows and columns.  The lookup Activity has a First Row Only checkbox if you only want the first row.  All data is returned from the Lookup Activity as json.  Multiple rows are returned as an json array.

Answer (score 0):

In ADF v1 you can use **CopyActivity** where **sqlReaderQuery** query will be `"$$Text.Format('exec MyStproc  \\'{1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}\\' ', WindowStart, WindowEnd)` where MyStproc will be something similar to :

```
create procedure MyStproc (@inputParam date)
as
select *
from aTable
where bField=@inputParam
```

Then you can store output as **JSON** and use it as needed for **Lookup** activity. 
I'm pretty sure you can adopt this approach to v2 as well.